# reboot Linux box from user space

Tags: linux, reboot

I need to reboot a Linux box from a user space process. I want to have the following behavior:

1. sync file systems
2. not attempt to gracefully stop processes, go to runlevel 5/6, etc., for I assume things are bad and that would fail

Can those requirements be achieved together at all?

I was planning to write a 'b' into proc/sysrq-trigger. Is there a better way? (No, that won't give me sync.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, do sync(1), kill -1, sync again, kill -9 -1, sync, poweroff -f.

That should do the trick, I guess!

Comment: the processes killed by the first 'kill' command may have written something to disk.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have root.

- the sysrq-trigger thing is fine, you just have to echo 's' a couple times into it first, which is an "Emergency Sync".
- You can also check out the '-n' option to shutdown(8). That's a canned way to do what you want. It just sends SIGTERM, SIGKILL, syncs and shuts down or reboots (-h or -r option.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but how do I know when 's' has been processed?

Comment: Not sure. I would look at the behavior of sysrq-trigger (does it block until the operation completes?) You may well get it for free.

If it is problematic, I would let shutdown -n do the job for you. Again, it bypasses init and does pretty much what you want without you having to call the shots manually.

Comment: if it blocks that's another problem, for sync may actually hang on me. But thanks anyway

Comment: Now that I think about it, yes, sync() is by definition synchronous! It *may* hang on you. How about fork()ing, and then syncing?

Comment: yes, I guess sync() being synchronous makes sense :)

It seems like I'm not so much looking for a solution here, but defining my problem. You're right, I either need to wait or I don't.

Comment: No, sync() is *not* defined to be synchronous.  It may be on some platforms, but it's not required by the POSIX standards, and it definitely is asynchronous on some other platforms.  See `man 2 sync`: "According  to  the  standard specification (e.g., POSIX.1-2001), sync() schedules the writes, but may return before the actual writing is done."

Answer (score 1):

This directly from sys/reboot.h :

```
#ifndef _SYS_REBOOT_H
#define _SYS_REBOOT_H   1

#include <features.h>

/* Perform a hard reset now.  */
#define RB_AUTOBOOT     0x01234567

/* Halt the system.  */
#define RB_HALT_SYSTEM  0xcdef0123

/* Enable reboot using Ctrl-Alt-Delete keystroke.  */
#define RB_ENABLE_CAD   0x89abcdef

/* Disable reboot using Ctrl-Alt-Delete keystroke.  */
#define RB_DISABLE_CAD  0

/* Stop system and switch power off if possible.  */
#define RB_POWER_OFF    0x4321fedc

__BEGIN_DECLS

/* Reboot or halt the system.  */
extern int reboot (int __howto) __THROW;

__END_DECLS

#endif  /* _SYS_REBOOT_H */
```

I believe RB_HALT_SYSTEM will handle all sync()s , etc. I usually do that myself, and finally trigger the reboot with RB_AUTOBOOT.

Answer (score 0):

On an ordinary distro, the simplest way to do this is:

```
system("/sbin/reboot -f");
```

This will sync all filesystems, then reboot immediately. Note that sysrq b will NOT sync.